# Should I join English Language Learners or should I not?

Tags: discussion, specific-site

I was scrolling through Stack Exchange sites, and I came across [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). Now, I am proficient in several languages, but English is my first. I realized I could answer a lot of the  questions presented, so... should I join? I could answer questions, but I'm also not *learning* English—I know it.

Comment: That's really up to you. I often spend a bit of time lurking in a community to try to decide its *value* for me. It is really a matter of opinion. If you think sharing your knowledge of the language with people who are learning would be mutually beneficial, sure, go ahead

Comment: Way to go with the -11 votes. You guys really showed him. I'm curious, what is the mindset of the eleventh person to downvote?

Answer (score 2):

ELL has quite a few native speakers present (including most of its mods). In fact, my [highest-voted answer on ELL Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/why-are-native-speakers-here/2860#2860) is about my rationale for joining:

> I'm a native speaker, and I'm here to learn.
>
> Learn in two major areas, in fact: first, there's a surprising amount about English itself that I only know intuitively, or even not at all.
>
> But the original and main reason I joined was to learn to be more effective at teaching English. And what better way than to do it?
>
> (It's also nice to do my bit in organizing English knowledge and helping various people with their problems, of course.)

I would say this covers most of the reasons a native speaker would want to join. If you don't want to help teach learners at all, of course, there's no real point in joining ELL; ELU is all you'd want. But even if that's not necessarily your biggest motivation, you can still learn a fair amount yourself in the process of helping non-native speakers figure out how English works.

The other answers on the question, which is in many respects a mirror of yours from a different perspective, are also worth reading.